# 'AttributeError' While Trying to Pass Instance Arguements in 'post_save'

Tags: python, django

I have searched everywhere for a solution but the suggested methods are either outdated or simply don't seem to work. It is strange that I could not find a clear answer for this in Django documentation as this seems to be a very common case.

I have extended the Django **"User"** model with my own, named "**Userprofile**", using a *one-to-one* relationship. I wish to store some additional data that is related to the User in this model. I have created a "**post_save**" signal handler to create a Userprofile instance and insert the additional data used *during account creation*.

**I have found out that I should be able o use the "instance" variable sent alongside the signal, but when I try to access it, I just get an error** that says

> Django Version:   1.10
>   Exception Type: AttributeError
>   Exception Value:
>   'User' object has no attribute '_dateofbirth'

I have verified that I can access the form data and the database is working fine as even though I get the error, an entry is created in the application's "auth_user" table.

My code is as follows; I am sure the problem is somewhere there but I just can't locate it:

**models.py**:

```
class Userprofile(models.Model):
user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
                            on_delete=models.CASCADE, 
                            related_name="userprofile")
dateofbirth = models.DateField()
gender = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=(
                                                ('M', 'Male'),
                                                ('F', 'Female')))
height = models.IntegerField()
weight = models.IntegerField()
notes = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)

@receiver(post_save, sender=settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, dispatch_uid="user_profile_creator")
def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    dateofbirth = getattr(instance, '_dateofbirth')
    gender = getattr(instance, '_gender')
    height = getattr(instance, '_height')
    weight = getattr(instance, '_weight')
    notes = getattr(instance, '_notes')
    if created:
        Userprofile.objects.create(user=instance,
                                   dateofbirth = dateofbirth,
                                   gender = gender,
                                   height = height,
                                   weight = weight,
                                   notes = notes)
```

**views.py**:

```
def signup(request):
if request.method == "POST":
    uform = UserForm(request.POST, instance=User())
    pform = UserprofileForm(request.POST, instance=Userprofile())

    if uform.is_valid() and pform.is_valid():
        email = BaseUserManager.normalize_email(uform.cleaned_data['email'])
        djangouser = User.objects.create_user(uform.cleaned_data['username'],
                                              email,
                                              uform.cleaned_data['password'])
        djangouser.last_name = uform.cleaned_data['last_name']
        djangouser.first_name = uform.cleaned_data['first_name']
        djangouser._dateofbirth = pform.cleaned_data['dateofbirth']
        djangouser._gender = pform.cleaned_data['gender']
        djangouser._height = pform.cleaned_data['height']
        djangouser._weight = pform.cleaned_data['weight']

        if pform.cleaned_data['notes']:
            djangouser._notes = pform.cleaned_data['notes']
        else:
            djangouser._notes = ''
        djangouser.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect('..')
```

Is it because I have defined the signal handler in the models.py? What am I doing so wrong that this wont work even when I try the exact same methods I have found online?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`User.objects.create_user` calls `save` directly, before the profile attributes have been added to the instance.

Don't do this. Create the Profile in the view alongside the user.

Comment: So you mean to say that my implementation actually fires the signal twice, but it fails since the first time it fires, the instance still does not have the necessary attributes?

Comment: Thank you! I added just changed the "if created:" to "if not created" to make sure it skips attempting to create a Userprofile in the first run. Can't believe I have wasted so much time on such a simple thing.